# Facebook API unable to get all rows of daily data even adding time_increment=1

Tags: facebook

I want to get daily Facebook ad data down to each ad level. The data is broken down by publisher platform and platform position. I am using the link below to try to get it, but even after adding time_increment=1, I still can only get one day data even I have daily ad run during the period. Could you please help with this?

`https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_XXXXXXXXX/insights?time_range={'since':'2023-01-01','until':'2023-05-20'}&time_increment=1&level=ad&fields=account_id,account_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,account_currency,ad_name,ad_id,adset_name,reach,frequency,attribution_setting,impressions,inline_link_clicks,spend&breakdowns=publisher_platform,platform_position`

Comment: @yacc, The link is the Facebook API URL link I use to get the data from FB API. Sorry for the confusion. Next time, I will copy it as text or add screencap to avoid confusion. It is the first time I post in Stackoverflow so still figuring out how to create a good post:) Anyway, I have found out how to solve the issue already.

Comment: @yacc, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Oh. I just figure out the reason. That is because the default no of output rows is 25. We could add limit to increase it to up to 5000. See the below example.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_XXXXXXXXX/insights?time_range={'since':'2023-01-01','until':'2023-05-20'}&time_increment=1&level=ad&fields=account_id,account_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,account_currency,ad_name,ad_id,adset_name,reach,frequency,attribution_setting,impressions,inline_link_clicks,spend&breakdowns=publisher_platform,platform_position&limit=5000`